# Выбор СУБД для написания программы C++

Tags: c++, база-данных

Здравствуйте. С какой СУБД проще всего работать новичку в C++?
На C# работал с Access, но теперь эта СУБД запрещена, поэтому нужна альтернатива... 
Запросы планируются следующих видов: выборка, обновление, удаление, добавление
максимум что сложного будет - взаимодействие сразу с двумя таблицами.
Особо важна тема подключения к выбранной СУБД. Я пытался работать с MySQL, но т.к. моя RAD Studio XE8 компилировала лишь приложения в 32-битном формате, драйвер ODBC не хотел корректно работать (windows 64 разрядная, поэтому качал соответствующий драйвер) и мне сыпалась куча ошибок. Хотелось бы избежать таких проблем. Итак, что можете посоветовать?)

Comment: [SQLite](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) чем не годится?

Comment: PostgreSQL всем годится :-)

Comment: LibreOffice Base :-)

Comment: Советовал бы SQLite. Несложно, не требует никаких внешних СУБД. При этом достаточно функциональна. Конечно, у нее упрощенно-сокращенные возможности, но для 90% задач их с головой хватит. Используется многим вполне серьезным софтом, кстати.

Comment: А можно пример взаимодействия с SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего Вам необходимо определить для каких целей требуется СУБД.

Если база нужна для удобного **локального** хранения как-либо внутренних настроек, данных или состояний - лучший вариант, как подсказывают комментаторы SQLite.

Только  посоветовал бы взять, например, обёртку [sqlite3pp](https://github.com/iwongu/sqlite3pp), дабы писать С++ код, а не С. Да и подключение может быть лишь импортированием заголовочного файла, что может оказаться огромным плюсом.

---

Если же будущее приложение **серверное**, то `MySQL`(исходя из неясности требований лучший вариант), а работать с ним при помощи обёртки [mysql++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/).